# Malformed JSON in Yahoo response

Tags: json, ruby, oauth, yahoo, yahoo-oauth

I am trying to get Yahoo user email by decoding ID Token like [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/decode_id_token.html#decode-id-token=) in Ruby. I have a token docoding it with `Base64.decode64`, parsing JSON and here problem come up. String I am trying to parse to JSON is invalid.

Sorry for this copy-paste have problem with formatting it.

START
{"at_hash":"pNgANAsIViDvJ7OCgSk1hw==","sub":"C4SNYQZSHET33BLBTUM3NU2KVP","email_verified":true,"birthdate":"1984","iss":"https://api.login.yahoo.com","profile_images":{"image64":"https://ws.progrss.yahoo.com/progrss/v1/user/C4SNYQZSHET33BLBTUM3NU2KVP/profile/picture
[XYNL΋XZ݌KӖTVU                   [Y^OM
              SLӕLՔ
                    ٚ[KX\O˚[Y^OLNL
                                 N[XY΋XZ݌KӖTVU
                                              SLӕLՔ
                                                    ٚ[KX\Bw6S##"vS3"#&GG3w2&w'726&w'72cW6W"E44UC34$ET$e&f7GW&Pͥȉ艕ULٕ}興Ր艑IYY])DYY9!5)4)9]9!EL4Ռa)]9aE}ѥ͕݅}ذЈ݅兡

END

It looks like the string is cut before its end. Is there any way to get proper JSON?
I am using Ruby 2.4.1

Comment: At a guess, that may have been a BASE64-encoded image? In which case, there is no bug here; you are simply unable to display a decoded image as ascii.

Comment: If that's binary image data you can't display it as a string, it will look like junk because it's not text.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this. But is this kind of problem with Yahoo Oauth I am getting this for all my users.

Comment: There's probably just control characters in the "profile_images" field that prevent it from being properly rendered in the console. Try `puts response.without("profile_images")` and it should display in full.

Comment: No it don't. There is `JSON::ParseError` for string above.